# What is a mod_rewrite rule to turn *.html to *.php?

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I need a rewriterule so if i type index.html i will show index.php

I mean i have files like, home.php, about.php and i want to be able to access them with .html too

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simplest solution:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.html$ $1.php
```

To support `htm`, `HTML`, `hTmL`, etc. use:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.html?$ $1.php [NC]
```

Comment: This will match if .html is found in the querystring of the original URL. For example, `/somepage.php?url=x.html` will match, although it is probably not the intended behavior.